# I adjusted the E-steps from 93 to 117.8, now it retracts all filament

Tags: creality-ender-3

I'm brand new to 3D printing and I have had to make so **many** adjustments just to get a decent print on the Ender 3. Its hardware is 4.2.2 and the firmware is 2.0.8.2. When I ordered it, it did not come with a user guide so I have spent the last week just getting it properly adjusted.

The last thing I just did was set the E-steps because I've been having a consistent extruder skipping issue and when I did the measurements for the E-steps, I got $\frac{90}{71}\times93 = 117.8$, and now right when it starts to print it expels all filament! I'm getting progressively exhausted from spending so many days just trying to get this right. I'll start a print and in the middle of the night the filament just stops printing and it turns out that after manually moving the extruder using the display, it was at least 50+ mm behind! I don't want to give up on this new hobby. So please, can someone please guide me in getting this right? I've 3D printed a few small objects when the thing shouldn't have even been functional, but doing a long print, it doesn't even clog! The filament just retracts so far. So far, here's what I have done.

- Fixed the X-axis wobble by adjusting the off-set nut
- Fixed the printer head wobble by adjusting the eccentric nut
- Unwound and rewound an amount of PLA roll
- Ensured the PTFE tube that goes into the printer head is flushed with nozzle and retainer clips are installed.
- Put stock PLA roll holder right up to the Z-axis screw so it wouldn't get caught or have too much tension.
- Leveled the bed with feeler gauges on all 4 furthest corners, I started with 0.2 mm and moved it so it's just barely touching the 0.1 mm gauge.

The list is small since in between each fix is a few hours of a failed print and researching each aspect of the printer.

To address the main point, I have been having an issue where the extruder skips, I wake up to the filament moved back beyond the nozzle, adjusted E-steps and now the filament un-extrudes about 100 mm.

Comment: I just reset creality slicer and now the issue is gone. I have no clue what happened but now the printer is functioning well. As a noob, if there's anything that Needs or should be addressed, Please tell me

Comment: Its still skipping randomly during the print. It just keeps retracting till no material comes out.

Comment: Worth noting (bit me in the back today) that all speeds in g-code (including extrusion rate) are in mm/min while in the slicer they are mm/s - an easy way to miscalculate by order of 60x

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that a change from 93 to 117.8 is correct. Filament hobs do not vary in diameter, tooth depth, filament squeeze, etc. by anywhere near that much. A measurement result that suggests you need more than a 5% change from the factory setting almost certainly means something is physically broken in your extruder. Maybe a crack in the arm, a spring with no tension, etc. You need to set the value back and track down what the real problem is before you try to tune esteps.

Comment: I just got this not even a week ago. How can I find out if its defective? I think that spring has plenty of tension since it takes some grip strength to pull it back. idk what to do bro, Im new so I need you to actually tell me what to even look for

Comment: @AnthonyPowell: Did you do your measurement for esteps with the extruder moving the filament free (disconnected from hotend) or with it pushing material thru the hotend? If the former, then something is almost surely mechanically wrong at the extruder side, but if the latter, it could very well be that you have a clog/jam making the extruder slip even when it's in okay condition. Re-reading, I notice it sounds like you removed the PTFE tube from the hotend and re-inserted it. This process is very easy to get wrong and can cause this kind of problem if you get it wrong.

Comment: "A measurement result that suggests you need more than a 5% change from the factory setting almost certainly means something is physically broken in your extruder."
I'd say an error in the measurement or calculation is even more likely.